# Use IPython %run magic in a loop

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I have a bunch of IPython notebooks that I want to run from another notebook. The notebooks are named

```
a1.ipynb
a2.ipynb
a3.ipynb

b1.ipynb
b2.ipynb
b3.ipynb
```

etc. I could just type

```
%run a1.ipynb
%run a2.ipynb
%run a3.ipynb

%run b1.ipynb
%run b2.ipynb
%run b3.ipynb
```

and that would work fine, but I want to be able to specify which letter/number combinations to run, like

```
for i in ['a', 'b']: # or ['a'], ['b'], etc
    for j in [1, 2, 3]: # or [1, 2], [1, 3], etc
        %run $i + str(j) + '.ipynb'
```

However, it appears that IPython ignores everything after the first space, so we get:

```
Exception: File `'a.py'` not found.
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Try constructing the name string first, and then use it as a `$ variable in the `%run` line.

Comment: works for me `%run '{i}{j}.ipynb'`